# Regex expression: can't set the length for firstname pattern eg. Mark-jacob john

Tags: regex

I wrote a regex for matching the following pattern

Sample strings

```
mark-jacob-john
mark jacob john
mark-jacob john
mark jakob john jen
mark jakob-john-jen
```

Regex

```
^[a-z]+((?:(\-|\s+)[a-z]+){0,})?$.
```

I want to set the length of the entire string to be between `{7, 100}`including the spaces and the hyphens. It doesn't matter how many first names I entered as long as the length is not less than `7`and greater than `100`.

How could I set the length and have the same pattern?

Comment: What regex environment (programming language) do you use? Some languages don't implement lookahead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a lookahead at the start to check for the character length.

```
^(?=.{7,100}$)[a-zA-Z]+(?:[\s-][a-zA-Z]+)*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yD8vZ3/10)